# Equality of Cardinality of a Power Set to a Set of Functions

Tags: discrete-mathematics, elementary-set-theory, cardinals

**Let `A` be a set. Define `D` to be the collection of all functions `f : A → {0, 1}`. Prove that `|P(A)| = |D|`
by constructing a bijection `F : P(A) → D`**

I know the power set of A contains `2^(|A|)` elements. To show that `|P(A)|=|D|`, I think I need to use CSB theorem. 
From what I'm understanding, the set `D` would have values like `{(a, 0),(a, 1)}`.

How do I go about solving this problem? I would be very grateful if someone explained this to me or gave an answer.

Comment: There are probably another dozen questions that could serve as a viable duplicate link.

Comment: I think it is helpful to fix an element in A and look at the possible values f can take on this Element, then apply this for all elements.